# Library of icons mostly used for iOS/swift/xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm looking for icons such as those: microphone, email, record, play, pause, stop, ...
is there a library of .png/.jpg available? I've tried to google for it but can't find one.
or should I do it with Xcode?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a super broad question, so I'll just give you the best advice I can think of. Here's a free library of mobile icons. They are used for IOS and Android:

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons

Comment: There is no special look & feel for iOS? So I can just re-use my already existing android app icons?

Comment: The only look and feel you should worry about is what you like and want to do, there's not set "standard" of icons. I don't use the icons I linked in my answer, but I use an icon set that cost me around $1,000. My icon set has thousands and thoiusands of icons, it's personal choice, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
https://icons8.com/web-app/new-icons/all

all the icons are free till a certain size, so if you need icons for buttons you'll be happy with that...